# How i draw a route with react-google-maps component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-google-maps

I'm traying to draw a route between two points with react-google-maps but is not working for me. Can u help me with this problem? Here's a example of my react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from 'react-google-maps';
import MapDirectionsRenderer from './app_map_directions_render';

const Map = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultCenter={props.defaultCenter}
      defaultZoom={props.defaultZoom}
    >
      {props.places.map((marker, index) => {
        const position = {lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude};
        return <Marker key={index} position={position}/>;
      })}
      <MapDirectionsRenderer places={props.places} travelMode={window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING} />
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
);

const AppMap = props => {
  const {places} = props;

  const {
    loadingElement,
    containerElement,
    mapElement,
    defaultCenter,
    defaultZoom
  } = props;

  return (
    <Map
      googleMapURL={
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
        googleMapsApiKey +
        '&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
      }
      places={places}
      loadingElement={loadingElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      containerElement={containerElement || <div style={{height: "80vh"}}/>}
      mapElement={mapElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      defaultCenter={defaultCenter || {lat: 25.798939, lng: -80.291409}}
      defaultZoom={defaultZoom || 11}
    />
  );
};

export default AppMap;
```

And my `MapDirectionsRenderer` Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { DirectionsRenderer } from "react-google-maps";

export default class MapDirectionsRenderer extends Component {
  state = {
    directions: null,
    error: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { places, travelMode } = this.props;

    const waypoints = places.map(p =>({
        location: {lat: p.latitude, lng: p.longitude},
        stopover: true
    }))
    if(waypoints.length >= 2){
    const origin = waypoints.shift().location;
    const destination = waypoints.pop().location;

    const directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: travelMode,
        waypoints: waypoints
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: result });
        }
      }
    );
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <h1>{this.state.error}</h1>;
    }
    return <DirectionsRenderer directions={this.state.directions} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To render a route Google Maps API provides [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), in case of [`react-google-maps` library](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) [`DirectionsRenderer` component](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/components/DirectionsRenderer.md) is available which is a  wrapper around [`DirectionsRenderer` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRenderer) which in turn:

> Renders directions obtained from the `DirectionsService`.

Assuming the data for route is provided in the following format:

```
const places = [
  {latitude: 25.8103146,longitude: -80.1751609},
  {latitude: 27.9947147,longitude: -82.5943645},
  {latitude: 28.4813018,longitude: -81.4387899},
  //...
]
```

the following component could be introduced to *calculate and render directions* via [`react-google-maps` library](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps):

```
class MapDirectionsRenderer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    directions: null,
    error: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { places, travelMode } = this.props;

    const waypoints = places.map(p =>({
        location: {lat: p.latitude, lng:p.longitude},
        stopover: true
    }))
    const origin = waypoints.shift().location;
    const destination = waypoints.pop().location;



    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: travelMode,
        waypoints: waypoints
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: result });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <h1>{this.state.error}</h1>;
    }
    return <DirectionsRenderer directions={this.state.directions} />;
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cacwgk)

---

For React `16.8` or above, `MapDirectionsRenderer` could be implemented (using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)) as below:

```
function MapDirectionsRenderer(props) {
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { places, travelMode } = props;

    const waypoints = places.map(p => ({
      location: { lat: p.latitude, lng: p.longitude },
      stopover: true
    }));
    const origin = waypoints.shift().location;
    const destination = waypoints.pop().location;

    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: travelMode,
        waypoints: waypoints
      },
      (result, status) => {
        console.log(result)
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          setDirections(result);
        } else {
          setError(result);
        }
      }
    );
  });

  if (error) {
    return <h1>{error}</h1>;
  }
  return (
    directions && (
      <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Exactly, now i get an error `'google' is not defined`

Comment: This is expected behavior since Google Maps API should be globally accessible, to resolve it try to put `/* global google */`   on top of file (where MapDirectionsRenderer component is declared)